# redirect from html to another page in aspx

Tags: html, asp.net

i include html page in aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <iframe src="HTMLPage.htm" frameborder="0" style="width: 184px" ></iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

in the html page there is a button and when i press it i want to go to another page.

```
window.location ="../Doh/doh.aspx?";
```

the problem is that the new page open in the iframe in the aspx page, and i want that it instead of the first aspx page.

can you help me?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
parent.window.location.href = "../Doh/doh.aspx?";
```

Comment: @OrK the button inside HTMLPage.htm does it trigger  a server side event or client side javascript?

Comment: @OrK maybe stupid question. But did you try a ctrl+f5 to reload the scripts? =)

Comment: i try F5 but in dont work, i clear cookies and its work. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing parent's window and set url

```
window.parent.window.location.href = '../Doh/doh.aspx?'
```

Comment: i try F5 but in dont work, i clear cookies and its work. thank you